# jQuery how to append images to more than one div

Tags: jquery, function, append

I am using jquery json to return images from flickr.  If I want to append all the image to one div thats not a problem.  What i want to do is return 36 images but append 1-9 images to div one and 10-18 to div two 19-27 to div three and 28-36 to div four.

Comment: How are you retrieving the images? Will it be an array, a JSON object, XML? (or rather, what type of variable/list will you have to work will and iterate through?)

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you're doing at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9KyaK/

```
$images.each(function( i ) {
    if( i % 9 === 0 )
        $images.slice(i, i + 9).appendTo('#div' + (i / 9) );
});
```

Assumes `$images` is the collection of images, and each div has an id of `div0', 'div1` etc.

---

**EDIT:** I had `.appendTo('#div' + i );` instead of `.appendTo('#div' + (i / 9) );`. Fixed and added an example.

---

**EDIT:** For your specific code, add this to the end of the `getJSON` callback. After the `for` loop.

```
var $flickr = $('#flickr'); 
var $images = $flickr.children('a');

$images.each(function( i ) {
    if( i % 9 === 0 ) {
        var newDiv = $('<div/>',{id:'div'+(i/9)}).appendTo($flickr);
        $images.slice(i, i + 9).appendTo( newDiv );
    }
});
```

Comment: @Chill: There isn't enough information to know what to do. I don't know anything about your HTML structure so that I could know where to append. If this line does the append: `$(THUM).append('<a href="' + l + '" rel="ChillBoxGroupFlickr" title="' + photo['title'] + '"><img src="' + t + '" /></a>');` then I'd imagine you'll need to replace `THUM` with something that will select the proper container. for example `$( '#cont_' + ~~(i / 9) ).append(...` if your container IDs are `cont_0`, `cont_1`, etc.

Comment: So where do you want to append them? Did you want to create new containers? And there's only 9 images. I thought there would be more.

Comment: if you refresh there should be 18 now

Comment: @Chill: There's more now, but I still can't tell where they should be appended. Do you need to dynamically create the containers based on the number of images that were returned?

Comment: I am currently appending the images all to one div #flickr.  The images are appended like so atm <a href="link to image on flickr"><img src="thumbnail of image on flickr" /></a>. What i would like to do is get the images from the div #flickr and append to new divs, say div1 div2 div3 etc or instead of appending all the images to div #flickr just append them 9 at a time to div0, div1,div2

Comment: @Chill: I updated my answer. Use the new code solution, adding it *after* the `for` loop *inside* the `getJSON` callback function. If it works, please remember to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. Thanks.